# Как реализовать такую лампочку на css ?

Tags: css, css3, веб-дизайн

Подскажите, можно ли средствами CSS создать копию такой картинки ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Это некий фонарик который должен иметь два состояния - включённый и выключенный

Comment: Сделайте это средствами Photoshop или другого граф. редактора. И потом с помощью html отобразите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
input{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.light{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:20px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at 50% 40%,white 20%,yellow 50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}
:checked+.light{
  box-shadow:none;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at 50% 40%,white 20%,gray 50%);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<span class="light"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно например как-то вот так:

```
.lamp.on
{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:25px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(white 20%,yellow 80%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px 1px rgba(235,220,7,1);
}

.lamp.off
{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:25px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(white 10%,grey 80%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(184,183,178,1);
}
```

Тогда в HTML'е у вас должно быть что-то такое:

```
<div class='lamp on'></div>
<div class='lamp off'></div>
```

Стоит поиграться с цветами для большего сходства.

Comment: Очень важна идентичность png картинки его CSS аналогу

Comment: @BlackStar1991 тогда просто возьмите png